# Are there applications which can only be used with a particular desktop environment?

Tags: desktop-environment

I am planning to migrate fully to GNU/Linux (Debian or Fedora, still undecided) and so far, I have read PDFs and other manuals as a starting guide. That being said, I have read about desktop environments and from my understanding, these are only an interface display, a way to choose one's preferred appearance (at least that's how I understand it). Then I came across these two apps which I am planning to use:

- **Gnome Boxes**: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes

  This app is for creating KVMs and I don't know if I get to run it in KDE since its webpage says that it is a Gnome app.
- **Cirkuit**: https://wwwu.uni-klu.ac.at/magostin/cirkuit.html

  This app is for drawing electrical diagrams and its documentation website says that it is a KDE4 app so again, I don't know if I would be able to run it in Gnome.

I really need to use both of these apps but I am quite doubtful whether I get to use both using my desktop environment of choice or not. I would be really grateful if someone can enlighten me about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying system is X11 (X11 on Gnu on Linux), a window-manager is just another app that runs on X11. It is a bit special as it manages other windows, and decorates them (adds title bar and frame). You will also only run one of them. However you can run tools such as xdotool, that does some of the managing at the same time. A desktop system is just a window-manager, and a few other bits: such as task-bar, launcher, clock, notification system, tray, multi-desktop controller, etc.

So Plasma the KDE desktop is a KDE application, in the same way that other KDE apps are KDE apps. In the same way that Excel is a Microsoft app (written by Microsoft). Both can run on Gnome. And vice versa.

KDE and Gnome refer to the creators of the software, not to the system that they run on. However they will use different libraries. On Debian installing a new app can take just a few k-bytes. The first time you install something that uses a different set of libraries, it will take M-bytes. Therefore it will use more persistent storage(disk), more RAM, and more cache. However this will not be worse that an app in Microsoft's windows.

Comment: thank you for that explanation. it took several reads to understand but still, when you say "both can run on Gnome", what are referring to? KDE apps and Microsoft Excel?

Comment: Yes both. You can run Excel with wine (on plasma or gnome desktop or ... ).

Answer (score 1):

You should have no problem. Having a different desktop environment or not using desktop environment at all will generally not be a limiting factor for using software like this.

Comment: So you're saying that even if Cirkuit is a KDE4 application, it can still be used in Gnome?

Comment: Yes it should work, but if you're not sure you could always try it out by booting your Linux distribution of choice with a usb and installing the software.

Comment: @billyandriam In most cases it would just mean downloading a lot of libraries of the other DE, but you'll still be able to run it. Personally, I used to run `kate` in non-KDE environments.

Comment: @Fiximan ok I will definitely give that a try. Thanks.